# How to Generate Aztec 2D Barcode

Tags: javascript, java, aztec-barcode

I am trying to implement a feature that will generate an Aztec 2D Barcode given some input and render the 2D barcode on a web page so that people can print out.

I searched around, found some 3rd party Java library I can use.

But my question is: this feature I am trying to implement, is it something I can render in the front-end, like using a Javascript to generate the barcode; or is it something I should use a 3rd party library to write Java code and generate the barcode? If both, which way is better and why?

I am very new to this; any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Generally this type of question "what do you all suggest for me to use?" is frowned upon because it shows a lack of effort. We're much more able to answer questions in the form of "I have tried X and it does not do what I expect it to do. Instead, I receive an error with text Y." If you intend to generate images, I suspect you can do that directly from your library. Have you tried the library? What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually both. 
You can use js libraries like [this awesome npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bwip-js) to create any type of barcode using javascript. Use it if you are comfortable with using npm packages. The downside is its size that is around 1MB (not minified and gzipped). Use it if most of your website functionality is around this feature.
I'm sure you can find other light way js alternative.
If you want a light way frontend you also can do it in java.